# How to query for an element in an array

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

The following documents are stored in CouchDB

```
{
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "_rev": "3-2882a4696d580cdef754a93c7e5e77e7",
    "comb": [
        "4-5",
        "4-6",
        "5-6"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "_rev": "2-1991a898a5457308e3a89253e695cef5",
    "comb": [
        "4-5",
        "5-6"
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is the map function

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.comb, null);
}
```

and `http://localhost:5984/comb/_design/snp/_view/by_test?key="4-6"` returns only

```
{"total_rows":2,"offset":0,"rows":[

]}
```

How is it possible to find an element in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to call `emit` for each element of the array:

```
for (var i in doc.comb) {
    emit(doc.comb[i], null);
}
```

Then your query will find all documents that have a comb array which includes the key specified in the query.

Comment: Thank you, but I had to change it to `emit(doc.comb[c], null);`.